# Jquery Export to excel Customisation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Jquery datatable and used jquery export to excel feature to export the table values into te excel.
Now I want to download this generated excel into a specified path. Currently it is being downloaded to the computer's download location, how to change this path?

Comment: Please add your code and what have you tried so far. I don't think you can change the download path. It is entirely up to browser.

Comment: As far as I know the client/browser controls  where to download files to. Don't think you can control that from the server. 

Also, JavaScript and Java are different things. Don't mix them up.

Comment: @911DidBush yes you can, by sending file data to server side or by choosing folder in client side

Comment: @JordiCastilla "choosing folder in client side" <- Yes, so its up to the client (usually a browser) where to download it, just as I said. Don't get what you mean by "sending file data to server side".

Comment: @911DidBush _its up to the client (usually a browser) where to download it_ no, you can force the destination folder into client from server. And yes, you can send **any** data you have in client side to server, for example, to store in database....

Comment: @JordiCastilla Really, you can force the download destination folder from server? How would you do that? And wouldn't that first require the client to send his filesystem information to the server, or how would the server even know if the folder it is trying to force to exists on the client side? I'm seriously interested in how that would work and never heard of something like that before.

Comment: @911DidBush yes, you can and yes you **must** communicate with server. I.e. ajax call to get destination folder for the client, then with data retrieved use javascript to check if folder exists (create it otherwise) and write the data. Java (server) and javascript (client) are totally different scope languages, but togheter work really nice if you know how.

Comment: btw @Abhilash you shoud improve your question to get an answer....

Comment: Guys, Is there any way to make this jquery excel as an email attachment from server side (java)